# Change metro app background using a image from Uri

Tags: c#, image, microsoft-metro

I am trying to change the background from black to a image from a URI, I have looked around and can only find examples on XAML code but what if I want to do this all programmatically?

Comment: What language (besides XAML) are you using for your project, and what is the superclass of your main window?

Comment: C# .net 4.5 making a metro grid app

Answer (score 1):

```
this.Background =
    new ImageBrush
    {
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage
        {
            UriSource = uri
        }
    };
```

assuming "this" is the layout root of the app and that the pages or other controls don't override the Background with their own backgrounds.

Comment: This does not change the background of the app :| any ideas? Currently its just default black

Comment: Perhaps your pages set Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" (Black) in their root Grids - that's what the default page template does. You would need to remove it.